# linux df and OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

Tags: linux, ubuntu, disk-space, ext3

I've got a weird inconsistency (although I'm probably just missing something quite basic).
While running some script that generates small files on my I disk, I constantly get this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

But when I run df -h, I get:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2              15G   12G  2.2G  85% /
udev                  502M  144K  502M   1% /dev
none                  502M     0  502M   0% /dev/shm
none                  502M   72K  502M   1% /var/run
none                  502M     0  502M   0% /var/lock
none                  502M     0  502M   0% /lib/init/rw
```

So am I low on disk-space or not?

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Maybe the script filled up a filesystem, detected the error and removed the file(s) as part of its termination process. What files does the script try to write to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably out of inodes. Try `df -i`.

Comment: hi @Shmulik2004, could you tell me how to solve it in detail!

Answer (score 0):

This may have several causes:

- a process is currently writing a large file, so the disk usage statistics aren't updated till the file is closed. In this case you have to check the total used space by running

> sudo du -k /your/path

- there are one or more deleted files which are still in use by some process, so the df utility doesn't take them into account when calculating the total disk usage; you can find these files by running

> sudo lsof / | grep deleted

- the filesystem runned out of inodes, which you can check by running

> sudo df -i /your/path